# Extracting keywords from English sentence

Tags: speech-recognition

I have been working on an API for my house lately, and have come across an interesting problem that I need to find a solution to. I thought I would get some input as to how best others think I should go about this:

The API that I have developed can control things such as my computer monitors, turning them on and off. Also the colored Wifi lights, setting the color and brightness.

The problem that I am having is that I am trying to implement voice control for the system, using googles Speech-to-text API I have captured and converted the speech to text. Sent the text to the server, but am unsure as to how best convert a English sentence into a command that I can send into the API to have executed.

My API works on three things, a category, function and arguments. in that order, for example

```
Monitors->set_state->id=1&new_state=False
```

Answer (score 0):

There are speech recognition toolkits which can execute on your server and listen for keywords without sending data to the internet. For example, [Pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net)

For example how to spot for keywords with python you can check [this example](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/kws_test.py).

This is implementation in Python, though other languages are also supported.